# Sidebar next page in Friggeri CV Template

Tags: templates, friggeri-cv, sidebar

I'm using `friggeri-CV` template from this site https://es.overleaf.com/latex/templates/friggeri-cv-template/hmnchbfmjgqh.

I have a problem when adding more sections in sidebar (aside), the sections do not go to the next page. I tried adding a new `aside` but the content page moves to another page. Is there any way to solve it?

Additionally, when I added `\lipsum` get another error:

```
LaTex Error: There's no line here to end.
```

`cv-style.cls`:

```
% -- Encoding UTF-8 without BOM

\ProvidesClass{cv-style}[2015/02/27 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}


\usepackage{lipsum}  
\DeclareOption{espanol}{\def\@cv@espanol{}}
\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Colors %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage[left=5.6cm,top=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{4D4D4D}
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{999999}

\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{66D9EE}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{FA2772}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FE9720}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{A7E22E}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{9358FE}
\definecolor{aquamarine}{HTML}{36AF90}

\definecolor{date}{HTML}{A4A4A4}

\ifdefined\@cv@print
  \colorlet{blue}{gray}
  \colorlet{red}{gray}
  \colorlet{orange}{gray}
  \colorlet{green}{gray}
  \colorlet{purple}{gray}
  \colorlet{aquamarine}{gray}
  \colorlet{fillheader}{white}
  \colorlet{header}{gray}
\else
  \colorlet{fillheader}{gray}
  \colorlet{header}{white}
\fi
\colorlet{textcolor}{gray}
\colorlet{headercolor}{gray}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Fonts %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont{Roboto-Regular}[Path=fonts/]
\newfontfamily\bodyfontit{Roboto-LightItalic}[Path=fonts/]
\newfontfamily\thinfont{Roboto-Thin}[Path=fonts/]
\newfontfamily\headingfont{RobotoCondensed-Bold}[Path=fonts/]

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor, Path = fonts/]{Roboto-Light}

\newcommand{\italica}[1]{%
    {\color{gray}\bodyfontit #1}%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Header %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\header}[2]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=2cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{40pt}{65pt}\color{header}%
      {\thinfont #1}{\bodyfont  #2}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{1cm}
  \vspace{-2\parskip}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Last updated command %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}

\newcommand{\sethyphenation}[3][]{%
  \sbox0{\begin{otherlanguage}[#1]{#2}
    \hyphenation{#3}\end{otherlanguage}}}
%\sethyphenation[<options>]{<language>}{<list of words separated by spaces>}

\ifdefined\@cv@espanol
  \setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
  \def\lastupdatedtext{Última Actualización el}
\else
  \setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
  \def\lastupdatedtext{Last Updated on}
\fi

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{0.01\paperwidth}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{0.01\paperwidth}

\newcommand{\lastupdated}{ 
  \begin{textblock}{10}(11.3, 0.05)
    \raggedleft
    \fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\color{date}\thinfont 
    \lastupdatedtext{} \today
  \end{textblock}}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Structure %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{parskip}

\newcounter{colorCounter}
\def\@sectioncolor#1#2#3{%
  {%
    \color{%
      \ifcase\value{colorCounter}%
        blue\or%
        red\or%
        orange\or%
        green\or%
        purple\or%
        aquamarine\else%
        headercolor\fi%
    } #1#2#3%
  }%
  \stepcounter{colorCounter}%
}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{
  {\par\vspace{\parskip}
  {%
    \LARGE\headingfont\color{headercolor}%
    \@sectioncolor #1%
  }
  \par\vspace{\parskip}}
}

\renewcommand{\subsection}[2]{
  \par\vspace{.5\parskip}%
  \Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} #2%
  \par\vspace{.25\parskip}%
}

\newcommand{\jobtitle}[1]{%
    {\color{gray}\bodyfontit #1}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% List environment %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{12.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}


% \newenvironment{entrylist}{%
% }{%
% }
% \renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
% \newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
% \par
%   \noindent\parbox[t]{%
%     \dimexpr\textwidth-12.8cm\relax}{\raggedright #1}\parbox[t]{12.8cm}{%
%     \textbf{#2}%
%     \hfill%
%     {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\par
%     #4\vspace{\parsep}%
%   }\par}  

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Side block %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}
\newenvironment{aside}{%
  \let\oldsection\section
  \renewcommand{\section}[1]{
    \par\vspace{\baselineskip}{\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} ##1}
  }
  \begin{textblock}{3.6}(1, 1.87)
  \begin{flushright}
  \obeycr
}{%
  \restorecr
  \end{flushright}
  \end{textblock}
  \let\section\oldsection
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Other tweaks %
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\RequirePackage[left=5.6cm,top=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle=CV/Resume \textbar{} Alejandro Pérez Londoño,
    pdfauthor=Alejandro Pérez Londoño,
    pdfsubject=CV/Resume%
    }
```

`main.tex`:

```
% -- Encoding UTF-8 without BOM
% -- XeLaTeX => PDF (BIBER)

\documentclass[]{cv-style}          % Add 'print' as an option into the square bracket to remove colours from this template for printing. 
                                    % Add 'espanol' as an option into the square bracket to change the date format of the Last Updated Text

\sethyphenation[variant=british]{english}{} % Add words between the {} to avoid them to be cut 

\begin{document}

\header{John}{Smith}           % Your name
\lastupdated

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION  -- In the aside, each new line forces a line break
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{aside}
%
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 050022
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
john@smith.com
%
\section{languages}
English mother tongue
Spanish fluency
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
\section{another item}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
Once Item
Another item
Another item
one item more
other items
\end{aside}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{skills}
  \vspace{-0.2cm}

Skill 1, skill 2, skill 3, skill 4, skill 5.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{experience}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
  {2014--Now}
  {COMPANY 3}
  {City, Country}
  {\jobtitle{Job Title}\\
  Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description.}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
  {2011--2014}
  {COMPANY 2}
  {City, Country}
  {\jobtitle{Job Title}\\
  Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description.\\
  Detailed achievements:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. 
    \item Achievement 2. Achievement 2. Achievement 2. Achievement 2. Achievement 2. Achievement 2.
    \item Achievement 3. Achievement 3. Achievement 3. Achievement 3.  
  \end{itemize}}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
  {2008--2011}
  {COMPANY 1}
  {City, Country}
  {\jobtitle{Job Title}\\
  Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description.\\
  Detailed achievements:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. 
  \end{itemize}}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
  {2007--2008}
  {COMPANY 1}
  {City, Country}
  {\jobtitle{Job Title}\\
  Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description.\\}
%------------------------------------------------

\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2010--2011}
{M.Sc. {\normalfont in Economics [Grade]}}
{University}
{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2004--2009}
{B.Eng. {\normalfont in Engineering Management [Grade]}}
{University}
{(Emphasis in ...)}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OTHER QUALIFICATIONS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{other qualifications}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2013}
{Qualification}
{Institution}
{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2011}
{Qualification}
{Institution}
{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{awards}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2014}
{Award name}
{Institution}
{Award description. Award description. Award description. Award description. Award description. Award description. Award description. }
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{interests}
  \vspace{-0.2cm}
\textbf{professional:} professional interest 1, professional interest 2 and professional interest 3.
\lipsum[2-4]
\begin{itemize}
\end{itemize}{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your code you forgot to load package `lipsum` in the preamble, I added it in the following code.

The second issue is that an friggeri-cv is designed to contain only one page, you want to have two pages.

So you have to add an `clearpage` after the end of the first page and to add a new environment (a second one) `aside` to your code containing the informations you want in the first column of the second page.

Please see the following code (important code marked with `<=====`)

```
% -- Encoding UTF-8 without BOM
% -- XeLaTeX => PDF (BIBER)

\documentclass[]{cv-style}          % Add 'print' as an option into the square bracket to remove colours from this template for printing. 
                                    % Add 'espanol' as an option into the square bracket to change the date format of the Last Updated Text
\usepackage{lipsum} % <=================================================

\sethyphenation[variant=british]{english}{} % Add words between the {} to avoid them to be cut 


\begin{document}

\header{John}{Smith}           % Your name
\lastupdated

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION  -- In the aside, each new line forces a line break
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{aside}
%
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 050022
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
john@smith.com
%
\section{languages}
English mother tongue
Spanish fluency
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
\end{aside}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SKILLS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{skills}
  \vspace{-0.2cm}

Skill 1, skill 2, skill 3, skill 4, skill 5.

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{experience}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
  {2014--Now}
  {COMPANY 3}
  {City, Country}
  {\jobtitle{Job Title}\\
  Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description.}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
  {2011--2014}
  {COMPANY 2}
  {City, Country}
  {\jobtitle{Job Title}\\
  Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description.\\
  Detailed achievements:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. 
    \item Achievement 2. Achievement 2. Achievement 2. Achievement 2. Achievement 2. Achievement 2.
    \item Achievement 3. Achievement 3. Achievement 3. Achievement 3.  
  \end{itemize}}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
  {2008--2011}
  {COMPANY 1}
  {City, Country}
  {\jobtitle{Job Title}\\
  Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description.\\
  Detailed achievements:
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. Achievement 1. 
  \end{itemize}}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
  {2007--2008}
  {COMPANY 1}
  {City, Country}
  {\jobtitle{Job Title}\\
  Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description. Job description.\\}
%------------------------------------------------

\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2010--2011}
{M.Sc. {\normalfont in Economics [Grade]}}
{University}
{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2004--2009}
{B.Eng. {\normalfont in Engineering Management [Grade]}}
{University}
{(Emphasis in ...)}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   OTHER QUALIFICATIONS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{other qualifications}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2013}
{Qualification}
{Institution}
{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2011}
{Qualification}
{Institution}
{\vspace{-0.3cm}}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{awards}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2014}
{Award name}
{Institution}
{Award description. Award description. Award description. Award description. Award description. Award description. Award description. }
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS SECTION ----- page 2 <====================================
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\clearpage % <==========================================================

\begin{aside} % <=======================================================
%
\section{another item}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
Once Item
Another item
Another item
one item more
other items
%
\section{contact}
123 Broadway
City, State 050022
Country
~
+0 (000) 111 1111
+0 (000) 111 1112
~
john@smith.com
%
\section{languages}
English mother tongue
Spanish fluency
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
%
%
\section{programming}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} R
VBA, SQL, Python
\LaTeX{}
\end{aside}


\section{interests}
  \vspace{-0.2cm}
\textbf{professional:} professional interest 1, professional interest 2 and professional interest 3.
\lipsum[2-4]
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum % <=======================================================
\end{itemize}{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

with the resulting second page:

[image: resulting page 2]